# JavaFX - loading FXML file error

Tags: parsing, javafx, builder, fxml, scene

I have strange problem which is concerned to loading FXML file using Scene Builder 1.0.
I have created a class **Warrning** and after that I add to my package a FXML file and called it **WarrningGUI**. Creator has created a Contoller class called **WarrningGUIContoller**. Until then everything was fine. I stared to create a layout for my application. After I added two raw Panels and turned on and off my FXML file in Scene Builder about 2-3 times something like that appeared:

[image]

And this was in "Detail":

[image]

And there are my project files:

http://www59.zippyshare.com/v/94923569/file.html

**Does anyone know what is going on?**

**Thanks for all help :)**

Comment: You are probably re-defining the `xmlns:fs`. Search in line 9, column 308, as the error says.

Comment: Probably I have found source of problem: when I run option "Make Contoller" it is adding a new line in FXML file, e.g after 2 times:
...
fx:controller="GUI.Addons.Alerts.WarrningGUIController
fx:controller="GUI.Addons.Alerts.WarrningGUIController>

Answer (score 0):

On NetBeans 7.3 onwards dont use "Make Controller" to update your controller file to reflect the updates. It will inject fx:controller every time "Make Controller" is used.